# Start server service with wildfly

Tags: windows, java, jboss, wildfly

I need to start a service with certain IP using Wildfly

Already follows tutorials

Wildfly start fine with local IP which is 127.0.0.1 also with 0.0.0.0

But when I change into mine or other IP it got error like this

```
11:12:58,057 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.network.interface.public: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.network.interface.public: WFLYSRV0082: failed to resolve interface public
        at org.jboss.as.server.services.net.NetworkInterfaceService.start(NetworkInterfaceService.java:98)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

11:12:58,123 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 IO threads with 64 max task threads based on your 4 available processors
11:12:58,156 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
11:12:58,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
11:12:58,224 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
11:12:58,236 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.18.Final
11:12:58,230 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
11:12:58,429 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
11:12:58,445 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\wildfly-20.0.0.Final\wildfly-20.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
11:12:58,452 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\wildfly-20.0.0.Final\wildfly-20.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
11:12:58,759 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("interface" => "public")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.network.interface.public" => "WFLYSRV0082: failed to resolve interface public"}}
11:12:58,827 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "jca")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["org.wildfly.transactions.global-default-local-provider"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["org.wildfly.jca.transaction-integration is missing [org.wildfly.transactions.global-default-local-provider]"]
}
11:12:58,833 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "ejb3"),
    ("service" => "timer-service"),
    ("file-data-store" => "default-file-store")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["org.wildfly.transactions.global-default-local-provider"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.ejb3.timerService.timerPersistence.default-file-store is missing [org.wildfly.transactions.global-default-local-provider]"]
}
11:12:58,836 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0459: Triggering roll back due to missing management services.
11:12:58,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:12:58,881 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
11:12:58,890 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
11:12:58,903 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.1.3.Final stopping
11:12:58,955 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
11:12:58,979 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 20.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 12.0.1.Final) stopped in 14ms
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm new to all this so please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the Jboss on different IP, execute domain.sh script with -bmanagement and -b tag.

Example: `./domain.sh -bmanagement {Your server IP} -b {Your server IP}`

No file edit will be required.